# Including list of params in OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation, openquery

I'm trying to get the values from an external Database server executing the following code:

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(8000), @VAR CHAR(2)
DECLARE @Prefixos VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT prefixo 
    FROM ARH.arh.UorPos
)
SELECT @Prefixos = COALESCE(@Prefixos + ', ', '') + prefixo 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY prefixo
--SELECT @Prefixos --print a list of values separated by comma. eg.: 1, 2, 3

SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DICOI_LINKEDSERVER,''SELECT * FROM ssr.vw_sigas_diage where cd_prf_responsavel in ('''''  + @Prefixos + ''''''') order by cd_prf_responsavel, codigo'
EXEC (@TSQL)
```

But I'm getting:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DICOI_LINKEDSERVER" returned message "ERRO: syntax error at the end of input;
>   No query has been executed with that handle".
>
> Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DICOI_LINKEDSERVER".

I've researched the above links to try to resolve it:

- [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)
- [including parameters in OPENQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378496/including-parameters-in-openquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Join query result to a single line of values separated by comma [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367162/join-query-result-to-a-single-line-of-values-separated-by-comma?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Can anyone help me to resolve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of quoting the quotes around `@Prefixos` try: `SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DICOI_LINKEDSERVER,''SELECT * FROM ssr.vw_sigas_diage where cd_prf_responsavel in ('  + @Prefixos + ') order by cd_prf_responsavel, codigo'')'`. Note the quote and closing parenthesis at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before running your query with EXEC, it's best to just check first how the generated SQL string will look like.

For example by selecting the variable

```
DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(8000), @VAR CHAR(2)
DECLARE @Prefixos VARCHAR(MAX);

WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT prefixo 
    FROM (values ('1'),('2'),('3')) q(prefixo)
)
SELECT @Prefixos = COALESCE(@Prefixos + ', ', '') + prefixo 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY prefixo

SELECT  @TSQL = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DICOI_LINKEDSERVER,''SELECT * FROM ssr.vw_sigas_diage where cd_prf_responsavel in ('''''  + @Prefixos + ''''''') order by cd_prf_responsavel, codigo'

select @TSQL as TSQL
-- EXEC (@TSQL)
```

Then you can visually check if there's something odd about it.
Or just try running that sql yourself and see if it fails or not.

From that T-SQL it returns this result :

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DICOI_LINKEDSERVER,'SELECT * FROM ssr.vw_sigas_diage where cd_prf_responsavel in (''1, 2, 3''') order by cd_prf_responsavel, codigo
```

Notice that there's a bit to many single-quotes in that string. 
When using an IN with numbers, the single-quotes are not needed.
And something is missing at the end.

```
...  in ('+ @Prefixos +') order by cd_prf_responsavel, codigo'');';
```

Comment: LukStorms, your solution is corretct. Thank you very much for sharing your knowledge. Congratulations!