# Flatten Query Result Rows Into Columns with Comma Separted Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, pivot

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    HICNo
    ,trr.CUS_ID
    ,TRRRunDate
    ,trr.LastName
    ,trr.FirstName
    ,trr.TRCCode
    ,trr.TRCDescr
    ,trr.TCCode
    ,trr.TRREffDate
    ,PBPID
    ,PriorPBPID
    ,LISLevel
    ,[LIS%]
    ,LISEffDate
    ,CONVERT (CHAR,INE_EV_DT,101) AS EventDate
    ,INE_USER_ID AS UserID
    ,tcl.TCL_TYPE_DESC AS [Description]
FROM 
    #AM_TRR_INS trr                                          
    JOIN ETLStaging.dbo.INS_INSURED ins ON trr.CUS_ID   = ins.INS_CUS_ID
    JOIN ETLStaging.dbo.INE_INSURED_EV ine ON ins.INS_ID = INE.INE_INS_ID
    JOIN ETLStaging.dbo.TCL_TYPE_CD_LOOKUP tcl ON 
            ine.INE_TYPE = tcl.TCL_TYPE_CODE
            AND tcl.TCL_ID = '12'
UNION 
(
    SELECT
        HICNo
        ,trr.CUS_ID
        ,TRRRunDate
        ,trr.LastName
        ,trr.FirstName
        ,trr.TRCCode
        ,trr.TRCDescr
        ,trr.TCCode
        ,trr.TRREffDate
        ,PBPID
        ,PriorPBPID
        ,LISLevel
        ,[LIS%]
        ,LISEffDate
        ,CONVERT (CHAR,INA_PRC_DT,101) AS EventDate
        ,ina.INA_USER_ID AS UserID
        ,tcla.TCL_TYPE_DESC AS [Description]

    FROM 
        #AM_TRR_INS trr                                          
        JOIN ETLStaging.dbo.INS_INSURED ins ON trr.CUS_ID   = ins.INS_CUS_ID
        JOIN ETLStaging.dbo.INA_INSURED_AUD ina ON ins.INS_ID= ina.INA_INS_ID
        JOIN ETLStaging.dbo.TCL_TYPE_CD_LOOKUP tcla ON 
            ina.INA_TYPE = tcla.TCL_TYPE_CODE
            AND tcla.TCL_ID = '12'  
)
```

That returns a result set like so

> 9876543A  123456789   02/13/2011
>     LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   011 Enrollment Accepted as Submitted    61  03/01/2011
>     002             NULL    02/04/2011                      MARKW       APPLICATION
>   9876543A  123456789   02/13/2011
>     LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   011 Enrollment Accepted as Submitted    61  03/01/2011
>     002             NULL    02/08/2011                      MARKW       NEW ID CARD
>   9876543A  123456789   02/13/2011
>     LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   011 Enrollment Accepted as Submitted    61  03/01/2011
>     002             NULL    02/08/2011                      MCSB473     INFORMATION
>   SENT TO CMS 9876543A  123456789   02/13/2011
>     LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME   011 Enrollment Accepted as Submitted    61  03/01/2011
>     002             NULL    02/08/2011                      MCSB475     REPLY RECEIVED
>   FROM CMS

I'm trying to flatten the results down to one line where the EventDate, UserID and Description columns are comma delimited and the results fit into one row and just using GROUP BY to flatten everything. I'm stuck- using XML PATH and COALESCE aren't working how I'd hoped...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column

Comment: Post the desired output as well, including formatting. e.g. will it be {eventdate,userid,description;eventdate,userid,description;...} in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

It´s also possible to define your own aggregate function using CLR integration in SQL Server 2005, http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/basharkokash/archive/2008/06/07/how-to-implement-your-own-aggregate-function-in-sqlclr-sql-server-2005.aspx