# Getting concatenated rows in ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Script :-

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
  ID int,
  ErrorMessage nvarchar(200)
)


INSERT INTO Category 
  (ID, ErrorMessage)
VALUES
  (1, 'efgh')

INSERT INTO Category 
  (ID, ErrorMessage)
VALUES
  (1, 'abcd')

INSERT INTO Category 
  (ID, ErrorMessage)
VALUES
  (1, 'ijkl')

INSERT INTO Category 
  (ID, ErrorMessage)
VALUES
  (2, 'efgh')

INSERT INTO Category 
  (ID, ErrorMessage)
VALUES
  (2, 'abcd')

INSERT INTO Category 
  (ID, ErrorMessage)
VALUES
  (2, 'ijkl')
```

Expected output

```
Id                 ErrorMessage
----------------------------------
1                  abcd,efgh,ijkl
2                  abcd,efgh,ijkl
```

Note that the category ids are grouped and the messages separated by comma are in the ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select C.Id
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + C1.ErrorMessage
        From Category As C1
        Where C1.Id = C.Id
        Order By C1.ErrorMessage
        For Xml Path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') As Categories
From Category As C
Group By C.Id
```

Comment: You may get XML entitization without using XML type and value extraction

Answer (score 2):

```
select A.ID, STUFF((
    select ','+B.ErrorMessage
    from Category B
    where B.ID = A.ID
    order by B.ErrorMessage
    for xml path ('a'), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
from Category A
group by A.ID
order by A.ID
```