# How to turn Columns into Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

If i have a table that looks like this:

```
    ID int
    Name varchar
    City1 varchar
    City2 varchar
    City3 varchar
    State1 varchar
    State2 varchar
    State3 varchar
```

I understand a normal SELECT statement it will return data like this:

```
    ID, Name, City1, City2, City3, State1, State2, State3
```

But how do i return the SELECT statement to return the multiple City/State's into different rows, and group them... So it looks like this:

```
    ID, Name, City, State
```

And instead of these being columns:  Color1,Color2,Color3 and State1,State2,State3

They would be just more rows in the SELECT statement where all other data remains the same, if 1,2,3 Is Not Null.

Any suggestions on how to approach this using the least amount of Code? Preferrably one SELECT statement that handles this all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query your table three times and use `union all` to combine the result.

```
select ID, Name, City1 as City, State1 as State
from YourTable
union all
select ID, Name, City2, State2
from YourTable
union all
select ID, Name, City3, State3
from YourTable
```

You can also do it in one query using a cross join and a couple of case statements.

```
select ID, 
       Name,
       case T.N 
         when 1 then City1
         when 2 then City2
         when 3 then City3
       end as City,
       case T.N 
         when 1 then State1
         when 2 then State2
         when 3 then State3
       end as State
from YourTable
  cross join (values(1),(2),(3)) as T(N)
```

Comment: How about when is not null only?

Comment: @ZeeTee - If you don't want null values you should add a where clause. `where City1 is not null` etc.

Comment: @ZeeTee - Not sure that I understand how you want to exclude not null values. If for instance City2 for one row has a null value would you still want to include City1 and City three for that row?

Comment: i want to exclude the rows that are null city