# Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

T-SQL gurus, what is causing the following procedure to return this error "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client."?

```
create function dbo.func_get_times_for_stop(@stopId as varchar(5))
returns varchar(max) as
begin 
    declare @arrival_times varchar(max)
    set @arrival_times = '';
    declare @arrival_time varchar(5)
    declare arrival_cursor cursor for
        select arrival from schedules where stopid=@stopId;

    open arrival_cursor;
    fetch next from arrival_cursor;
    while @@fetch_status = 0
       begin
          fetch next from arrival_cursor into @arrival_time;    
          set @arrival_times += ',' + @arrival_time;    
       end;
    close arrival_cursor;
    deallocate arrival_cursor;

    return  @arrival_times;
end;
```

I am simply trying to return a scalar which comprises the string concatenated from arrival times. I do not see where I am returning a select statement.

Comment: Related: [SQL Server: Can I comma delimit...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Comment: @OMG Ponies, thanks for related link.  This would be even nice if I can get it to work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be this line?

```
fetch next from arrival_cursor;
```

It should be fetching into `@arrival_time`.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
fetch next from arrival_cursor;
```

you need

```
fetch next from arrival_cursor into @arrival_time;
```