# Output results from a single select statement as one row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

I have a bunch of values in a data source that i am trying to output as one single row:

```
SELECT
    '|| Id == "' + cast(ID as varchar(100)) + '"'
FROM 
    dbo.CAItem
WHERE 
    isactive = 1
```

This is the correct data, but I would like to output it as a single row instead of individual rows for each result so that the my return would be one single row like this:

```
|| Id == "4431" || Id == "4436"
```

Comment: If this is display only, why can't you do this application side?  Although, at minimum, you're going to need some sort of delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `GROUP_CONCAT()` function in SQL Server, however [`STRING_AGG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

In the meantime, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(ID INT);

INSERT @a SELECT 4431 UNION ALL SELECT 4436;

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT '|| Id == "' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), ID) + '"'
  FROM @a -- WHERE Isative = 1
FOR XML PATH('')) AS x(n);
```