# How to get a comma seperated value for the following DB table scenario

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

How to get the following output from a table in MSSQL 2005 ?

```
Input
-----

main_idn notice_id       group_name    employer_name
    1         20        State Client      Unknown
    2         20        Canada Corp       Unknown
    3         20        Unknown           Pacific Bell
    4         30        State Client      Unknown 
    5         30        Reality Corp      Unknown
    6         30        Unknown           Bell Labs
    7         30        Unknown           AT&T

Output 
------

notice_idn  group_name                                    employer_name
20          State Client,Canada Corp,Unknown              Unknown , Unknown , Pacific Labs
30          State Client,Reality Corp.Unknown,Unknown     Unknown , Unknown , Bell Labs ,  AT&T
```

In something like MYSQL I can write a simple query like :

from table get notice_idn , group_concat(group_name) as group_name , group_concat(employer_name) as emp_name group by notice_idn

Comment: Search StackOverflow. There are plenty of answers to similar questions.

Comment: I have seen many such 'duplicates' but I am not able to correlate as much , because the join construct is confusing to me . Can anyone tell me a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column) which I like, however would you please try with below solution though both are same kind of solution, thanks for your time.

```
SELECT outerT.notice_idn,

       STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + innerT.group_name
                FROM TargetTableName innerT
               WHERE innerT.notice_id = outerT.notice_id
            GROUP BY innerT.notice_id, innerT.group_name
             FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'), ''), 1, 1, '') group_name,

       STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + innerT.employer_name
                FROM TargetTableName innerT
               WHERE innerT.notice_id = outerT.notice_id
            GROUP BY innerT.notice_id, innerT.employer_name
             FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'), ''), 1, 1, '') employer_name             

FROM TargetTableName outerT
GROUP BY outerT.notice_id
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much . I am new to DB queries . I need to learn the idea used in this solution - but perfect .

Comment: You are most welcome, just keep learning and go on...