# concat multiple record in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation

I have three tables:

1-

```
employee(emp_id,emp_name) values(1,"ahmed mohamed")
```

2-

```
attach_emp(emp_id [f.k] ,attach_id[f.k]) junction table

values(1,1)
values(1,2)
```

3-

```
attachment(attach_id,attachname)

values(1,"a")
values(2,"b")
```

I want the result to be:

```
emp_id   emp_name        Attachment
1        ahmed mohamed   a,b
```

How do I do this join and concatenation between records?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly decent-looking article on this here that might be of some use:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

In particular, the section entitled "Concatenating values when the number of items is not known" looks relevant, for what it's worth.