# SQL - Combining results (rows) of one value

Tags: sql

I think this is a newbie question but I am not coming up with anything is my searches.

Two tables:

Table1 Name: CLIENT

```
Inactive    ClientID    Name
0           1001        Fred
0           1002        Cindy
0           1003        John
0           1004        Sherry
```

Table2 Name: JOURNAL

```
ClientID    RecordType  Date       Comments
1001        Note       01-01-2012   TXT1
1001        Note       01-01-2012   TXT2
1003        Note       01-01-2012   TXT3
1001        Note       01-02-2012   TXT4
1002        Note       01-06-2012   TXT5
1003        Note       01-22-2012   TXT6
1003        Note       01-23-2012   TXT7
```

If have no way of knowing how many rows there will be in JOURNAL for a particular ClientID. Could be none or many.

If I use the following which gives me everything EXCEPT 1004 so that is my first issue.

```
SELECT FROM CLIENT.InActive, CLIENT.ClientID, CLIENT.Name, JOURNAL.Comments
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOURNAL ON CLIENT.ClientID = JOURNAL.ClientID
WHERE CLIENT.Inactive = 0 and JOURNAL.Date > '2011-01-01'
```

What I am trying to do is combine the results of the JOURNAL.Comments into one record as such.

```
ClientID    Name    Comments
1001        Fred    TXT1, TXT2, TXT4
1002        Cindy   TXT5
1003        John    TXT3, TXT6, TXT7
1004        Sherry
```

**UPDATED**: I am pulling data from a Faircom ODBC source so I am limited and unable to use CREATE for a TMP table. Am using Excel or MSQUERY as I cannot get SMS to connect to FairCom driver.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. YES ... I am aware of alias'. Wanted to keep it simple as I am having a hard time grasping this one.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. Somehow it got butchered upon submission. PLease let me know if you cannot follow. Thx.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Comment: The reason you aren't getting 1004 in the result is that you use JOURNAL in your where clause.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, you are not getting the `1004` record because of where you have placed the `date` filter, move it to the `left join`:

```
select c.inactive,
  c.clientid,
  c.name,
  j.comments
from client c
left join journal j
  on c.clientid = j.clientid
  and j.dt > '2011-01-01'
where c.inactive = 0
```

Second, you did not specify the RDBMS, so here are some options:

In SQL Server you can use `STUFF()`:

```
select c.inactive,
  c.clientid,
  c.name,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + comments 
              from journal j
              where j.clientid = c.clientid
                 and j.dt > '2011-01-01'
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE

            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
from client c
where c.inactive = 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02747/4)

In MySQL use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
select c.inactive,
  c.clientid,
  c.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(j.comments, 'NULL'))
from client c
left join journal j
  on c.clientid = j.clientid
  and j.dt > '2011-01-01'
where c.inactive = 0
GROUP BY c.inactive,
  c.clientid,
  c.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02747/19)

In Oracle you can use the `listagg()` function:

```
select c.inactive,
  c.clientid,
  c.name,
  LISTAGG(j.comments, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.clientid) AS comments
from client c
left join journal j
  on c.clientid = j.clientid
  and j.dt > to_date('2011-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
where c.inactive = 0
GROUP BY c.inactive,
  c.clientid,
  c.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0f99/2)

Comment: `+1` for you, do you in DB2? :)

Comment: @JohnWoo if I had access to DB2 I would add it.

Comment: Why would I be getting "Literal not allowed in ON condition"? I suspect it is the ' around the value. Using either MSQury or excel connecting to a FairCOM ODBC driver.

Comment: @user1650365 what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another version using `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT a.inactive , 
       a.clientid,
       a.name,
       SUBSTRING(d.CommentsList,1, LEN(d.CommentsList) - 1) CommentsList
FROM   client a
       CROSS APPLY
       (
          SELECT comments + ', ' 
          FROM journal AS B 
          WHERE A.clientid = B.clientid 
          FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (CommentsList)
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02747/8)

special thanks to **bluefeet** for the `SQLFiddle DDL`

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2008 this is the solution, add your where clause

```
SELECT  ClientID   ,Name ,Comments= STUFF((SELECT ','+ yt.Comments
                                                    FROM JOURNAL yt
                                                    WHERE yt.ClientID = sc.ClientID            
                                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
         FROM CLIENT AS sc
```