# Return multiple values in one column

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**Employee**:

```
Empid Ename Eage Eadd Ephone
1      x     23   b    677
2      y     24   h    809 
3      z     34   u    799
```

**Department**:

```
Did  fkEmpid dname ddescription
123    1     test   test
234    1     test1  test1
667    2     hello  hello
```

Finally I want something like this

```
Ename Eage  Eadd Ephone  dname
x      23     b   677     test,test1
y      24     h   809     hello
z      34     u   799     null
```

Please help me with the SQL

Comment: Duplicate of: <insert 1000 questions here>

Comment: 1. What is your RDBMS? 2. What exactly is your question? 3. Show us your attempt before you expect us to help you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - Combining results (rows) of one value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291564/sql-combining-results-rows-of-one-value)

Comment: +1 Good question, apologies for the downvotes.  You can find a solution for this by searching for "group concat <your database name>", [example search here](https://www.google.com/search?q=sqlserver+group+concat)

Comment: @Andomar - I'm not sure on which alternate reality this would be considered a good question. Variants of it are asked daily so it shows no research effort. Also omits the rather crucial information that they are using HSQLDB.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Many people benefit from asking and answering this question.  To regulars, this might not be very interesting, but regulars are not SO's only constituency.  As to why you can't Google this question, that's because you don't know what to Google for.  I've seen several people try, IRL, and they're intelligent and smart, but they don't figure out that "group concat" is the magic word.

Comment: @Andomar - If you google the question title "Return multiple values in one column" are you telling me you don't see relevant results?

Comment: @MartinSmith: It doesn't make sense to me either.  But I know for sure well-meaning people can't figure it out by themselves.

Answer (score 5):

It certainly would be nice to know the target RDBMS. But this question is asked so often so let's try and list'em all (at least popular ones) side by side.

For **SQL Server**:

```
SELECT e.Ename, e.Eage, e.Eadd, e.Ephone, d.dname
  FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT fkEmpid,
         STUFF((SELECT ',' + dname 
                    FROM Department 
                   WHERE fkEmpid = t.fkEmpid 
                     FOR XML PATH('')) , 1 , 1 , '' ) dname
    FROM Department t
   GROUP BY fkEmpid
) d
    ON e.Empid = d.fkEmpid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12fcf2/5)** demo

For **Mysql**, **SQLite**, **HSQLDB 2.X**:

```
SELECT e.Ename, e.Eage, e.Eadd, e.Ephone, d.dname
  FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT fkEmpid,
         GROUP_CONCAT(dname) dname
    FROM Department t
   GROUP BY fkEmpid
) d
    ON e.Empid = d.fkEmpid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/952ae/1)** demo (MySql)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/952ae/1)** demo (SQLite)

For **Oracle 11g**:

```
SELECT e.Ename, e.Eage, e.Eadd, e.Ephone, d.dname
  FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT fkEmpid,
         LISTAGG (dname, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dname) dname
    FROM Department t
   GROUP BY fkEmpid
) d
    ON e.Empid = d.fkEmpid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ac90/1)** demo

For **PostgreSQL 9.X**:

```
SELECT e.Ename, e.Eage, e.Eadd, e.Ephone, d.dname
  FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT fkEmpid,
         string_agg(dname, ',') dname
    FROM Department t
   GROUP BY fkEmpid
) d
    ON e.Empid = d.fkEmpid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/952ae/4)** demo

Output in all cases:

```
| ENAME | EAGE | EADD | EPHONE |      DNAME |
---------------------------------------------
|     x |   23 |    b |    677 | test,test1 |
|     y |   24 |    h |    809 |      hello |
|     z |   34 |    u |    799 |     (null) |
```

Comment: HI Peterm thnks for the answers.. and sorry that i dint tell my RDBMS.. I am using HSQLDB

Comment: @ShivangiGupta - Looks like `GROUP_CONCAT` is available for [versions >= 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978291/return-multiple-values-in-one-column#comment24532063_16978291)

Comment: @ShivangiGupta Just use MySql version of the query and let me know if it helped. It works just fine on HSQLDB 2.2.

Comment: @Peterm- I tried MySql but it is not working for me.It is showing this error Routine (group_concat) can not be resolved.

Comment: @ShivangiGupta What version of HSQLDB are you on?

Comment: @Peterm:- I am using the old version 1.x, i think for this lower version GROUP_CONCAT will not work.

Comment: @ShivangiGupta No, it won't. You might consider to upgrade to 2.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Considering **RDBMS** as **`SQL SERVER 2008`**

```
select E.Ename,E.Eage,E.Eadd,E.Ephone,D.dname
into Table1
from Employee E
left join Deparment D on E.Empid=D.fkEmpid

select t1.[Ename], t1.[Eage], t1.[Eadd], t1.[Ephone],
STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.dname
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.Ename = t1.Ename
      AND t2.Eage=t1.Eage
      AND t2.Eadd=t1.Eadd
      AND t2.Ephone=t1.Ephone
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS Names
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Ename,t1.[Eage], t1.[Eadd], t1.[Ephone];
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67d98/3)**