# select inner join table id vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, pivot, inner-join

I used this first time.

```
SELECT classroom .cls_id, 
   classroom.cls_name, 
   u1.users_id as users_id1,
   u2.users_id as users_id2
FROM   classroom 
   INNER JOIN clsown 
           ON clsown.cls_id = classroom .cls_id 
   INNER JOIN users AS u1 
           ON clsown.users_id = u1.users_id 
   INNER JOIN users AS u2
           ON clsown.users_id = u2.users_id
```

I get this:

```
cls_id  cls_name  users_id1  users_id2

1 -------- room1 ------- 1 --------- 1
1 -------- room1 ------- 2 --------- 2
2 -------- room2 ------- 3 --------- 3
2 -------- room2 ------- 4 --------- 4
```

i want to see

```
cls_id  cls_name  users_id1  users_id2

1 -------- room1 ------- 1 --------- 2
2 -------- room2 ------- 3 --------- 4
```

I do not know how to do inner join. What am i doing wrong?

Thank for answer.

Comment: Where are the 2 `users_id` coming from?  Your query is constraining where those fields must be equal in `clsown` and `u1` so I'm confused how you are wanting them to be different.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhiftrhrt0i0a9w/kkk.JPG

Comment: @Harajukuzz Are you only ever going to have 2 users?  What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @bluefeet yes cls_id have 2 users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server there are a few ways that you can *pivot* the data.

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select cls_id,
    cls_name,
    MAX(case when rn = 1 then users_id end) user_id1,
    MAX(case when rn = 2 then users_id end) user_id2
from
(
    SELECT cr.cls_id, 
        cr.cls_name, 
        u1.users_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cr.cls_id order by u1.users_id) rn
    FROM classroom cr
    INNER JOIN clsown co
        ON co.cls_id = cr.cls_id 
    INNER JOIN users AS u1 
        ON co.users_id = u1.users_id 
) d
group by cls_id, cls_name;
```

Or you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select cls_id,
    cls_name,
    user_id1, 
    user_id2
from
(
    SELECT cr .cls_id, 
        cr.cls_name, 
        u1.users_id,
        'user_id'+cast(ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cr.cls_id order by u1.users_id) as varchar2)) col
    FROM classroom cr
    INNER JOIN clsown co
        ON co.cls_id = cr.cls_id 
    INNER JOIN users AS u1 
        ON co.users_id = u1.users_id 
) d
pivot
(
    max(users_id)
    for col in (user_id1, user_id2)
) piv;
```

Comment: how  where   users_id1= 1 or users_id2 =1

Comment: @Harajukuzz I don't understand what you are asking, please ask a new question with the new details?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664926/select-inner-join-column2-null new question

Answer (score 1):

The query that you are noting here would actually require a pivot as you want to take the unique values for cls_id and cls_name and then order the users into columns.

I wrote [this article](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/pivoting-the-dynamic-way-102722) back in 2009 that shows how to do something like this.  It should help

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using `Mysql` as your `RDBMS`, if so you can make use of [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to display the `records` as per your [need](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eea725/3), but in a different form. i.e] This query will stuff all the additional `coloumns` you wanted, into a single `cell` separated by a `separator`.

```
SELECT classroom .cls_id, 
       classroom.cls_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(u1.users_id ORDER BY u1.users_id SEPARATOR ', ') Users 
FROM   classroom 
       INNER JOIN clsown 
               ON clsown.cls_id = classroom .cls_id 
       INNER JOIN users AS u1 
               ON clsown.users_id = u1.users_id
       Group by classroom .cls_id
```

The above query will return records like below,

```
cls_id  cls_name    users

  1      room1       1,2

  2      room2       3,4
```

**EDIT:**  *[Reference for achieving the above result in Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)*