# select inner join column2 NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join

> table clsown
>
> id cls_id users_id
>
> 1----1---------1
>
> 2----1---------2

sql

```
select cls_id,
cls_name,
MAX(case when rn = 1 then users_id end) user_id1,
MAX(case when rn = 2 then users_id end) user_id2
from
(
SELECT cr.cls_id, 
    cr.cls_name, 
    u1.users_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cr.cls_id order by u1.users_id) rn
FROM classroom cr
INNER JOIN clsown co
    ON co.cls_id = cr.cls_id 
INNER JOIN users AS u1 
    ON co.users_id = u1.users_id and u1.users_id =1
) d
group by cls_id, cls_name;
```

i get this

```
cls_id cls_name users_id1 users_id2
  1     room1       1        NULL
```

i want see

```
cls_id cls_name users_id1 users_id2
  1     room1       1         2
```

Comment: @bluefeet users_id2 NULL

Comment: Please see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87e1c/2 -- I cannot reproduce the isse

Comment: If the demo is not correct, then please expand your data set in your question and explain what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a `and u1.users_id =1` in it, which is why you're getting the results you're seeing. bluefeet's SQL Fiddle shows the results without that and it looks like it works fine.

```
select cls_id,
    cls_name,
    MAX(case when rn = 1 then users_id end) user_id1,
    MAX(case when rn = 2 then users_id end) user_id2
from
(
    SELECT cr.cls_id, 
        cr.cls_name, 
        u1.users_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cr.cls_id order by u1.users_id) rn
    FROM classroom cr
    INNER JOIN clsown co
        ON co.cls_id = cr.cls_id 
    INNER JOIN users AS u1 
        ON co.users_id = u1.users_id 
) d
group by cls_id, cls_name;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87e1c/2)

Comment: I added the correct code and the demo to your answer.

Comment: I made ​​it a success.

Comment: ON co.cls_id = cr.cls_id and cr.cls_id in(select cls_id from clsown where users_id=1)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `and ul.users_id = 1` from the `on` clause:

```
select cls_id,
cls_name,
MAX(case when rn = 1 then users_id end) user_id1,
MAX(case when rn = 2 then users_id end) user_id2
from
(
SELECT cr.cls_id, 
    cr.cls_name, 
    u1.users_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by cr.cls_id order by u1.users_id) rn
FROM classroom cr
INNER JOIN clsown co
    ON co.cls_id = cr.cls_id 
INNER JOIN users AS u1 
    ON co.users_id = u1.users_id
) d
group by cls_id, cls_name;
```

Comment: yes but show all users

Comment: @Harajukuzz It will, yes. With the current design you'd have to pull from the result set from the query above `WHERE user_id1 = 1` if you just wanted the one result set.

Comment: @Harajukuzz . . . It will show two usesrs, which is what you specify in the query in your questino.