# Concatenating a List of of sites and count of occurrences into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, concatenation

Using this page:  [Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

... I've been able to come up with results such as this:

[image]

Using this query:

```
SELECT
    [Client ID],
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [Location (counts)]
           FROM (
                SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [Client ID]
                    , ltrim(str([Store Num])) + ' (' + ltrim(str(count([Store Num]))) + ') ' [Location (counts)]
                FROM @tbl_coreData
                GROUP BY [Store Num], [Client ID]
                ORDER BY COUNT([Store Num]) DESC) tblThis 
           WHERE ([Store Num] = Result.[Store Num] 
             AND [Client ID] = Result.[Client ID]) 
           FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS BATCHNOLIST
FROM @tbl_coreData AS Result
GROUP BY [Client ID], [Store Num]
```

I want the list to be ordered by The count of occurrences (the number in parenthesis). My attempt at this was the

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
    [Client ID]
```

and

```
ORDER BY COUNT([Store Num]) DESC
```

but this didn't work.

How can I make the concatenated values be presented in order of descending occurrence?

As always, all help is welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much fidgeting and using Hogan's suggestion, I have come up with this:

```
DECLARE @Heroes TABLE (
    [HeroName]      VARCHAR(20),
    [HeroFriend]    VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Heroes ( [HeroName], [HeroFriend] )
VALUES  ( 'Superman', 'Aquaman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Batman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Wolverine' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Batman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Wolverine' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Batman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Ironman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Wolverine' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Batman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Ironman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Wolverine' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Batman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Ironman' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Wolverine' ), 
        ( 'Superman', 'Wolverine' ), 
        ( 'Batman', 'Wolverine' );

with pre as (
  SELECT
    [HeroName],
    count([HeroName]) [locationcount],
    '(' + ltrim(str(count([HeroName]))) + ') ' + [HeroFriend] [Concat]
  FROM @Heroes
  Group By [HeroName],
           [HeroFriend]
)

Select DISTINCT
       [HeroName],
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + [Concat]
              FROM (
                    SELECT TOP 100 [HeroName],[Concat]
                    FROM pre
                    order by locationcount desc
              ) tblThis 
              WHERE ([HeroName] = Result.[HeroName]
                 )
              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS [Loc Counts]
From pre AS Result
```

For some reason SQL didn't like it much when I tried to do the Concatenation and/or sorting by counts on the fly.  The code would run without error, but the sorting was disregarded.  But putting those into the "with" block beforehand solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
with pre AS
(
  SELECT 
    [Client ID],
    ltrim(str([Store Num])) as [Store Num]
    count([Store Num]) as locationcount
  FROM @tbl_coreData
  Group By [Store Num], [Client ID]
)
Select [Client ID],
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + [Location (counts)]
              FROM (
                SELECT [Client ID], [Store Num] + ' (' + locationcount + ') ' [Location (counts)]
                FROM pre
                Order By locationcount desc
              ) tblThis 
              WHERE ([Store Num] = Result.[Store Num] AND [Client ID] = Result.[Client ID]) 
              FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS BATCHNOLIST
From pre AS Result
order by locationcount desc
```

Comment: This is helpful in that I have never used a "WITH" clause.  I was able to order values by adding *FROM pre Group By locationcount, [Store Num], [Client ID]* into the subquery, however this orders ascending by default.  the *Order By* statements don't work in the subquery, although they don't throw an error either.

Comment: @n8 There should be no reason to order by in the sub-query (pre).  Any time you use it you will be doing a select and can add an order by clause in that select.  I'm not sure where you are not seeing the correct ordering.

Comment: I don't understand why my edit of your answer was rejected, I made two minor revisions so that it would run.  You have an *order by* in your subquery, maybe you mean to exclude that instead of making it work?  As for my comment above, the *order by* that I mentioned using did not ultimately work, it seems that my preliminary results were a fluke of my test subject set.  So the question remains open.

Comment: @n8 the orderby in the sub-query should change what order the comma separated results are in.  the order by at the end should change the order of the rows.