# Combine two rows into one row. like average function but instead it will concat

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL Server 2000.

What I want to do is like average function but instead it will concat.

Is there a way that I can do that?

For example I have this data.

```
Name   |   Score
Name1  |   50
Name1  |   70
```

and the output should be like this.

```
Name  |  Score
Name1 |  50,70
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Answer (score 0):

Use below query for your reference.

**Query**

```
Select main.doctorID,
       Left(Main.submain,Len(Main.submain)-1) As 'Title'
From
    (
        Select distinct ST2.doctorID, 
            (
                Select convert(varchar,ST1.encounterid) + ',' AS [text()]
                From dbo.enc ST1
                Where ST1.doctorID = ST2.doctorID
                ORDER BY ST1.doctorID
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) submain
        From dbo.enc ST2
    ) [Main]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use CLR, look at this example :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165055%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

It provides a custom aggregate that concatenates values, which results in very clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this simple query.

```
Select Name, (Select SUBSTRING((SELECT ', '+Score from TableName for XML 
Path('')) ,2,8000)) from TableName
```

You will have result like

ColumnName |  val1, val2,  ....

Comment: You may need to convert Score value from `int` to `varchar`.

Comment: Does this work on SQL server 2000? Sorry I forgot to tell the version I'm using.

Comment: sorry. it supported only  >= 2005  version of SQL

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
SELECT Name, 
(SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ', '+CAST(Score AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM my_table FOR XML Path('')) ,2,1000)) AS Score 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY name;
```

[Fiddle for reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ed486/1)

If you are using `SQL Server 2000`, then try to create a function as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(name VARCHAR(50),score INT);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('Name1',50);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('Name1',70);
```

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION commaseparated(@name VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @score VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @score = COALESCE(@score + ', ', '') + CAST(score AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM my_table
WHERE name = @name 
RETURN @score
END

SELECT 
name, 
score = dbo.commaseparated(name) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Does this work on SQL server 2000? Sorry I forgot to tell the version I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

check this.

```
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
    ('name1', 50),
    ('name1', 70)


SELECT * FROM @T

Select name ,
STUFF((SELECT ',' + cast( score as varchar(50)) FROM @T WHERE (
name=Result.name) FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS BATCHNOLIST
From @T AS Result
GROUP BY name
```

[Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)