# How to concatenate a column value with single quotes in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to concatenate a column value with single quotes and a comma in sql?

```
select tpaa_id  from dbo.Sheet
where tpaa_id is not null
```

At present query returns, value as ..

```
ABC123
ABC456
```

We have around 1000 records.

I expect to return as

```
'ABC123',
'ABC456',
```

Comment: There are many similar questions and answers here like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2046037/4519059) , Have you checked them?

Comment: There is always similar to one another..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the values with comma , use below statement...

select field 1 || ',' from table name;

Comment: Thank you Bhargav,I wasn't aware of pipeline syntax in the select query. I will do that. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 7):

Use this construction

```
SELECT CONCAT(CHAR(39), MyString ,CHAR(39)) FROM Table

return '<MyString>'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use variable for concatenation:

```
declare @result nvarchar(max)

select @result  = isnull(@result + ', ', '') + '''' + tpaa_id  + '''' 
from dbo.Sheet
where tpaa_id is not null

select @result
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, Query works .. however i changed nvarchar(max) to 4000 limit

Comment: This syntax is giving me a problem : declare @result nvarchar(max)

Comment: @goofyui what exactly problem are you experiencing with this line of code?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply  concatenate the columns using the query

```
select ''''||tpaa_id||''''||','  from dbo.Sheet
where tpaa_id is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If its SQL Server 2017 and above

`SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(tpaa_id,''''), ',')  FROM dbo.Sheet`

Comment: I have to check the syntax string_agg

Answer (score 0):

> Use three single quotes to concatenating

```
select  'insert into [LookUpModeofTransfer] values('''+Name+'''' +',1'+')'  from 
(SELECT  name,isActive FROM [dbo].[LookUpModeofTransfer]
 )a
```

Answer (score 0):

when we do String Concatenation in sql
we need to use `ISNULL` function----------------

```
DECLARE @str1 NVARCHAR(20)
DECLARE @str2 NVARCHAR(20)
SET @str1 = NULL
SET @str2 = 'str2'
select @str1 + @str2
select ISNULL(@str1,'') + ISNULL(@str2,'')
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
hi 
'UPDATE LinkedMySQLDB.TableToUpdate AS a SET a.MySQLField=''updated'' WHERE a.ID IN (LocalMSSQLDB.LocalTable.ID) ;' 

This is a string constant but you need a value for LocalMSSQLDB.LocalTable.ID.

Declare @ldb int;
set @ldb = select LocalMSSQLDB.LocalTable.ID

'UPDATE LinkedMySQLDB.TableToUpdate AS a SET a.MySQLField='' + value + '' WHERE a.ID IN (' + @ldb + ') ;'
```