# Output from my query not quite right, possibly subquery for this?

Tags: sql

Need some help structuring my query. I think I need a subquery, but I am not quite sure how to use them in my context. I have the following tables and data,

```
people
ID, Name
1, David
2, Victoria
3, Brooklyn
4, Tom
5, Katie
6, Suri
7, Kim
8, North
9, Kanye
10,James
11,Grace


relationship
peopleID, Relationship, relatedID
3,Father,1
3,Mother,2
6,Father,4
6,Mother, 5
8,Mother,7
8,Mother,9
11,Father,10
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.name, f.ID, f.name, m.ID, m.name 
FROM people AS p 
LEFT JOIN relationship AS fr ON p.ID = fr.peopleID 
LEFT JOIN people AS f ON fr.relatedID = f.ID 

LEFT JOIN relationship AS mr ON p.ID = mr.peopleID 
LEFT JOIN people AS m ON mr.relatedID = m.ID 
WHERE p.ID IN(3,6,8,11) 
AND (
     mr.Relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother') 
OR   fr.Relationship IN('Father','Stepfather')
    )
```

The query above outputs the following data

```
3,Brooklyn,1,David,1,David
3,Brooklyn,1,David,2,Victoria
3,Brooklyn,2,Victoria,2,Victoria
6,Suri,4,Tom,4,Tom
6,Suri,4,Tom,5,Katie
6,Suri,5,Katie,5,Katie
8,North,7,Kim,7,Kim
8,North,9,Kanye,7,Kim
8,North,9,Kanye,9,Kanye
11,Grace,10,James,10,James
```

I kind of understand what is going on, hence the reason I am thinking I probably need a subquery or possibly a union to get the parents first and then build on those results. I am trying to output the following, can anyone help please?

```
3,Brooklyn,1,David,2,Victoria
6,Suri,4,Tom,5,Katie
8,North,9,Kanye,7,Kim
11,Grace,10,James,, <-should display no mother details (same for the father if father was not in the data)
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I have no possibility to check a query right now. Does this work?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.name, f.ID, f.name, m.ID, m.name 
FROM people AS p 
LEFT JOIN relationship AS fr 
       ON p.ID = fr.peopleID
      AND fr.relationship IN ('Father','Stepfather')
LEFT JOIN people AS f
       ON fr.relatedID = f.ID
LEFT JOIN relationship AS mr
       ON p.ID = mr.peopleID
      AND mr.relationship IN('Mother','Stepmother')
LEFT JOIN people AS m 
       ON mr.relatedID = m.ID 
WHERE p.ID IN(3,6,8,11)
```

The point is to get rid of using (WHERE A OR B) together with LEFT JOIN. It brings too much uncertainty in result's logic

Comment: That seems to work from initial tests, didn't realise you could use an IN filter in the join itself. Always thought the IN had to go in the WHERE clause.

Comment: A IN ('B', 'C' )has no difference from (A = 'B' OR A = 'C'), if that matters. Left join will always bring you something - and will it be NULL or actual values depends on join filter. BTW if you want to filter people with no parents present you'll have to use (..) WHERE (f.name IS NOT NULL or m.name IS NOT NULL) - in such cases where clause is impossible to replace

Comment: select cast(p.id as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + p.name + ( SELECT cast(p1.id as varchar(max)) + ',' + p1.name FROM relationship r1 inner join people p1 on r1.relatedID = p1.ID where r1.peopleID = p.id for xml path('') ) from relationship r inner join people p on p.ID = r.peopleID group by p.ID,p.name

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ??

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name, p1.ID, p1.Name
FROM relationship r
    INNER JOIN people p ON p.ID = r.peopleID
    INNER JOIN people p1 ON p1.ID = r.relatedID
```

select cast(p.id as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + p.name + ( SELECT cast(p1.id as varchar(max)) + ',' + p1.name FROM relationship r1 inner join people p1 on r1.relatedID = p1.ID where r1.peopleID = p.id for xml path('') ) from relationship r inner join people p on p.ID = r.peopleID group by p.ID,p.name

let me know if you want more.

Comment: select cast(p.id as nvarchar(max)) + ',' + p.name + (
 SELECT cast(p1.id as varchar(max)) + ',' + p1.name
 FROM relationship r1
  inner join people p1 on r1.relatedID = p1.ID
 where r1.peopleID = p.id
 for xml path('')
)
from relationship r
 inner join people p on p.ID = r.peopleID
group by p.ID,p.name

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've already accepted an answer, but I still want to provide the mine :

```
WITH familly AS
(
    SELECT
         child.ID AS childID
        ,child.Name AS childName
        ,Relationship AS relationship
        ,parent.ID AS parentID
        ,parent.Name AS parentName
    FROM relationship
    LEFT JOIN people AS child ON child.ID = peopleID
    LEFT JOIN people AS parent ON parent.ID = relatedID
)
SELECT
     t.childID
    ,t.childName
    ,STUFF(ISNULL((
        SELECT ', ' + CAST(x.parentID AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ', ' + x.parentName
        FROM familly x
        WHERE x.childID = t.childID
        GROUP BY x.parentID, x.parentName
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') [Parents]
FROM familly t
WHERE t.childID IN(3,6,8,11) 
GROUP BY t.childID, t.childName
```

There're less `LEFT JOIN` and more readable. You should start the jointure 
by using the table `relationship`, so:

- on one side, you can join `people` as children
- on the other side, you can joint `people` as parents.

Then, I've used the statement `WITH` to provide better readability. At the end, the
operation [STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) concatenates multiple strings (parents) into one row.

References :

- [Stack Overflow: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)
- [MSDN: STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)