# Can STUFF function return NULL values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull, for-xml-path

I'm looking at the following link:

[Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The query used in the solution is exactly what I need, but also need to return NULL values.

```
SELECT t.TicketID,
   STUFF(ISNULL((SELECT ', ' + x.Person
            FROM @Tickets x
           WHERE x.TicketID = t.TicketID
        GROUP BY x.Person
         FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), ''), 1, 2, '') [No Preceeding Comma]
FROM @Tickets t
GROUP BY t.TicketID
```

This works great if each [TicketID] has an associated [Person].

But if the Person is NULL, for the TicketID, I need to return just the TicketID and have the Person show as NULL or blank. I'm having trouble removing the ISNULL cleanly.

From this:

```
[TicketID], [Person]
 T0001       Alice
 T0001       Bob
 T0002       Catherine
 T0002       Doug
 T0003       Elaine
 T0004       NULL
```

To this:

```
[TicketID], [Person]
 T0001       Alice, Bob
 T0002       Catherine, Doug
 T0003       Elaine
 T0004       NULL
```

Comment: You need to write `PIVOT` on top of your query... hope you can explore

Comment: Is this a question? Or attempts at discussion? Lookup MSDN, and go forward methodically. Also, there is no reason you cannot extract, transform, and then use your data. Simplify the process and it might help finding ways to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT t.TicketID,
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + COALESCE(t2.Person, '<NULL>')
               FROM @Tickets t2
               WHERE t2.TicketID = t.TicketID
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
              ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'
                     ), 1, 2, ''
             ) as Persons
FROM @Tickets t
GROUP BY t.TicketID;
```

The `GROUP BY` in the subquery is not necessary, unless you have duplicates.

Comment: I'm receiving the following error: "The stuff function requires 4 argument(s)."

Comment: @bojackh . . . Ooops, I left your original syntax in the answer for that portion of the code.  The above should be the correct formulation.

Comment: Thanks, looks like we needed to take out the , '')

Comment: Hmm....it's still not returning the NULL.  I played with it a bit more and was able to get it to work by left joining the entire query above on the TicketID.  Probably not optimal but at least works...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your problem... This should work *out-of-the-box*. Maybe I did not understand the problem...

- removed the `NOT NULL` for `Person`
- added one more line with TicketID="T0004" and a `NULL` as person
- removed the `ISNULL` from your query
- simplified your code

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Tickets TABLE (
    [TicketID] char(5) NOT NULL,
    [Person] nvarchar(15)  NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Tickets VALUES
    ('T0001', 'Alice'),
    ('T0001', 'Bob'),
    ('T0002', 'Catherine'),
    ('T0002', 'Doug'),
    ('T0003', 'Elaine'),
    ('T0004', NULL);

SELECT t.TicketID,
   STUFF(
           (
            SELECT ', ' + x.Person
            FROM @Tickets x
            WHERE x.TicketID = t.TicketID
            FOR XML PATH ('')
            ),1,2,'') AS [No Preceeding Comma]
FROM @Tickets t
GROUP BY t.TicketID;
```

The result

```
TicketID   No Preceeding Comma
T0001      Alice, Bob
T0002      Catherine, Doug
T0003      Elaine
T0004      NULL
```