# PROC SQL: collect_set or group_concat equivalent?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Given the following data,

```
data tmp;
   input class $ age gpa graduated;
   datalines;
    A 16 2.47 1
    B 13 3.65 1
    A 13 2.04 0
    B 12 2.3 0
    C 15 3.58 1
;
run;
```

I'm seeking this output:

```
class|unique_ages
A|13, 16
B|12, 13
C|15
```

Coming from the world of Hive/Apache Spark, functions like `collect_set` + `concat_ws` have worked well, but I haven't found the equivalent in SAS.

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT
        class
        * some grouping function on `age`;
    FROM tmp
        GROUP BY class
    ;
QUIT;
```

Similar answers look like this: [Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column). Group-by row aggregation and concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

proc sql does not have that functionality but you can do it in datastep using first. and last.

```
data tmp;
input class $ age $  gpa graduated;
datalines;
A 16 2.47 1
B 13 3.65 1
A 13 2.04 0
B 12 2.3 0
C 15 3.58 1
;
run;


 proc sort data=tmp out =have;
 by class age;
 run;

data want(keep = class group_ages);
set have ;
by class;
retain group_ages;
length group_ages $20.;
if first.class then group_ages = ' ';
else group_ages= catx(',', group_ages, age);
if last.class then output;
run;
```

Comment: Shouldn't if first.class then group_ages = '  '; be if first.class then group_ages = age; instead?